# Does MarkLogic support Object.values()?

Tags: object, marklogic

Take an object:
`let keyObject = {"Dog": "red", "Cat": "blue", "Parrot": "yellow"}`

I am able to use `Object.keys(keyObject)` function to access the keys, but get an error when using `Object.values(keyObject)`

**Error: Object.values is not a function**

Does MarkLogic not support this function yet?

Answer (score 2):

`Object.values()` is a new function that will be included in ES 2017.

It is available in ML 10, thanks to the upgrade of the V8 engine: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/v8-engine-upgrade-in-marklogic-10/.